# How I can remove last element with slice and split the in one link that has every thing words and "/:?

Tags: javascript, split, slice

I want to slice last element I should first separate with split("/") then slice last element but the problem is How I can put ("/") on where I separate 
Imagine:

```
var link=
"https://www.youtube.com/shakira"
```

I want to remove /shakira". I write this bellow code :

```
var store;
store=link.split("/").slice(0,-1)
```

I can remove last element but remove ("/") too ! How can I put them in where they were !

Comment: So, you want to remove that last part, but _keep_ the `/`?

Comment: string replace using regex? `.replace(/[^/]+$/, '')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Better to use the tools provided

Remove the path:

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/shakira")
console.log(url.protocol+"//"+url.hostname+"/")
```

Remove the last part of the path:

```js
const url = new URL("https://youtube.com/shakira/bbbbb/aaaaa/cccc")
const path = url.pathname.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/")
console.log(url.protocol+"//"+url.hostname+path+"/")
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what the OP wants... As far as I can tell, he just wants to remove the last element of the url, so `www.x.com/foo/bar` would become `www.x.com/foo/`

Comment: Yes, It isn't work for me maybe I have more than one word after it imagine : "https://www.youtube.com/shakira/bbbbb/aaaaa/cccc"